# Laravel Auth::User() performance

Tags: laravel

I have a question that whenever we call `Auth::User()` then its execute the query to fetch record or it have a saved instance?

Example 1

```
echo Auth::User()->name;
echo Auth::User()->email;
echo Auth::User()->phone;
```

Example 2

```
$userInfo=Auth::User();

echo $userInfo->name;
echo $userInfo->email;
echo $userInfo->phone;
```

Which one should be used performance wise?

Comment: the current authenticated user is saved on the guard after the first time it is retrieved ...  those are functionality the same but the first is requiring an extra function call every time but that isn't a large issue ... also you could have looked at the queries performed and answered the query question

Comment: FYI: You can use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar or https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope to inspect queries generated by a page.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer and example

Call to the database will be made only the first time you call `Auth::user()`, after that Laravel will store the user data and each call after that will get the stored instance rather then query the database again.

You can take a look at the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php` file under `user()` method. This is the code I copied from my current project which uses Laravel 7.x and this is the function called by `Auth::user()`.

```
/**
     * Get the currently authenticated user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function user()
    {
        if ($this->loggedOut) {
            return;
        }

        // If we've already retrieved the user for the current request we can just
        // return it back immediately. We do not want to fetch the user data on
        // every call to this method because that would be tremendously slow.
        if (! is_null($this->user)) {
            return $this->user;
        }

        $id = $this->session->get($this->getName());

        // First we will try to load the user using the identifier in the session if
        // one exists. Otherwise we will check for a "remember me" cookie in this
        // request, and if one exists, attempt to retrieve the user using that.
        if (! is_null($id) && $this->user = $this->provider->retrieveById($id)) {
            $this->fireAuthenticatedEvent($this->user);
        }

        // If the user is null, but we decrypt a "recaller" cookie we can attempt to
        // pull the user data on that cookie which serves as a remember cookie on
        // the application. Once we have a user we can return it to the caller.
        if (is_null($this->user) && ! is_null($recaller = $this->recaller())) {
            $this->user = $this->userFromRecaller($recaller);

            if ($this->user) {
                $this->updateSession($this->user->getAuthIdentifier());

                $this->fireLoginEvent($this->user, true);
            }
        }

        return $this->user;
    }
```

### Debugbar options

Also as the comment before me pointed out, it is good to download Debugbar for Laravel https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. It will enable you to take a look into queries being executed, views being rendered, requests being sent, and much more.

Other option is Laravel's native solution https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope. I have never personally used it and IMO the first one is simpler to use.

### Notes on good practice

Although both examples will essentially do the same thing, I think it is much better to use the second example. Not because of the performance, but rather to make your code readable in future. If you define the user only one time and assign `Auth::user()` result to it, in future it will be more obvious what it is, and plus, you can easily change what are you assigning to the `$userInfo` variable (maybe you want to get user from another guard in future, etc.) without having to change it on N places throughout the code.